# 'no [query] registered for [filtered]'

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, elasticsearch-5

I am using haystack with elasticsearch backend for full text searching. I am wanting to show the search result using ajax. However I am getting an error of `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'no [query] registered for [filtered]')` .

I build the index using `python manage.py rebuild_index --verbosity=2` and it showed me 4 furnitured indexed as well

I am just into this so I did not understand the below solution

[Django/Haystack error: elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception',...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361321/django-haystack-error-elasticsearch-exceptions-requesterror-transporterror400)

Here filter should be replace with bool solution is provided but i dont know where is that file to change

version of library used

Django==1.11.6

elasticsearch==5.6.1

django-haystack==2.6.1

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is that Django Haystack only supports [ElasticSearch 1.x or 2.x](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#elasticsearch) and indeed you are using 5.6.1

You'll have to downgrade the ElasticSearch service for it to work.

The other solution explained that you cannot do those kind of queries, and how should the direct query to ElasticSearch works, in this case Haystack is the one doing the request to ElasticSearch, which you can't (or would be difficult) to change.

Comment: Also it worth to mention that ElasticSeach 2.x is not compatible with Java 9 or higher.